# How to get author meta into post endpoint in api v2

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to output all of the fields in the json result but seem to be using the object incorrectly. I want to add author meta fields to the post endpoint.

This doesn't work

```
    function slug_show_author_meta( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
      return  get_the_author_meta( $object[ 'id' ], $field_name );
    }
```

This does but only gives me one field

```
    function slug_show_author_meta( ) {
      return  get_the_author_meta('user_nicename');
    }
```

Ideally I'd just like to get user_nicenaem, user_email, display_name, nicename, first_name and last_name. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
function wpse_20160421_get_author_meta($object, $field_name, $request) {

    $user_data = get_userdata($object['author']); // get user data from author ID.

    $array_data = (array)($user_data->data); // object to array conversion.

    $array_data['first_name'] = get_user_meta($object['author'], 'first_name', true);
    $array_data['last_name']  = get_user_meta($object['author'], 'last_name', true);

    // prevent user enumeration.
    unset($array_data['user_login']);
    unset($array_data['user_pass']);
    unset($array_data['user_activation_key']);

    return array_filter($array_data);

}

function wpse_20160421_register_author_meta_rest_field() {

    register_rest_field('post', 'author_meta', array(
        'get_callback'    => 'wpse_20160421_get_author_meta',
        'update_callback' => null,
        'schema'          => null,
    ));

}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'wpse_20160421_register_author_meta_rest_field');
```

Comment: tried it and gave me back post_author_meta": [0] I named the field and added it to the post. `register_rest_field('post',
   'post_author_meta',
   array(
    'get_callback'    => 'slug_show_author_meta',
    'update_callback' => null,
    'schema'          => null,
   )
  );`
before I saw your code i did try get_user_data and I can get get back nicename, displayname etc but not last or first. I changed your code to include `$post_author = (int) $object['author'];

    $user_data = get_userdata($post_author);`
but still returns the wrong fields

Comment: Whoops! I didn't notice you want to get post author meta :). Just updated the answer.

Comment: Ha. You def pointed me in the right direction and I got it. Thanks! I tried yours and that works as well. See what I did that was similar.

Comment: Cheer! Welcome to WPSE :)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'user_puntuacio' );

function user_puntuacio() {
    register_rest_field( 'user', 'puntuacio',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'get_user_puntuacio',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}


function get_user_puntuacio( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    return get_user_meta( $object[ 'id' ], 'puntuacio', true );
}
```

Note that 'puntuacio' is the custom user meta I wanted to add.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick thanks to @Dan for pointing me in the right direction.

```
    function slug_show_author_meta( $object ) {
       $post_author = (int) $object['author'];
        $array_data = array();

        $array_data['login'] = get_the_author_meta('login');

        $array_data['email'] = get_the_author_meta('email');

        $array_data['user_nicename'] = get_the_author_meta('user_nicename');

        $array_data['first_name'] = get_user_meta($post_author, 'first_name', true);

        $array_data['last_name'] = get_user_meta($post_author, 'last_name', true);

        $array_data['nickname'] = get_user_meta($post_author, 'nickname', true);

        return array_filter($array_data);
    }
```

it returns

```
     "post_author_meta": {
     "login": "billy"
     "email": "billy@email.com"
     "user_nicename": "billy"
     "first_name": "Billy"
     "last_name": "Boy"
     "nickname": "billy"
      }
```

Comment: If answer works for you then please accept the answer by Dan instead of posting a thank you post!

Comment: I got you but not really a thank you post. I posted the code I wrote that got me what I wanted that Dan had sparked. Apparently we were working it at the same time and came up with slightly different methods.